# 08 Malibu won't turn over

Tags: starting

08 Malibu had an engine with a bad head gasket I had a 09 Malibu they had a good running motor but smashed so I put the good running motor in the 08 Malibu and now it it says bad crank position sensor but I know the motor was running yesterday. So I took the computer from the 09 and put it in the 08 but now there's a lock in the gauge cluster turn the key to run and it won't turn over what do I do how do I fix this help please

Comment: Now I got it to turn over but it still says crankshaft position sensor system not learned

Comment: You need to have the car running to do a ckp relearn once done that will clear that code. Check for injector pulse you may need to do a passlock relearn.

Comment: I did the passlock relearn last night that's how I was able to get it to turn over.

Comment: Is the engine running? If not check for injector pulse and spark

Comment: The three female ends inside the plug on the knock sensor  looks ok. The motor that was in the car before also would crank over but had no spark I didn't check the codes because I was putting a good running engine in it. And thought that would fix the problem.

Comment: I'm at work right now I know I have gas cause I could smell.it from cranking it over but I didn't check spark because of.the codemim getting p0315.

Comment: No the engine is not running. I don't know if this has anything to do with it but the radio has no power also?

Comment: I have no spark but I do have pulse at the injectors . In for got to mention that I purchased the car from an auction and it looks like it may have been a theft recovery car. If that sheds any light on problem I'm having.

Comment: Passlock is injector pulse and starter inhibit. What engine do you have? Can you confirm power ground and coil trigger?

Comment: I had  fuse 43 missing put one in and  it starts and stalls out

Comment: You should answer your own question regarding the the no crank and crank no start issues and open a new question concerning the start stall issue. I’ll put this out there though clean the throttle and do an idle relearn. See if it helps.

Comment: The engine ran great not even 48 hours ago that's what gets me

Comment: Was missing fues 43 now starts but stalls